# User-defined type not defined error while using ProgressBar access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to implement a progress bar for access form. When calling method it throws an error saying user-defined type not defind and error marking in Form_ProgressBar

```
Private Sub exampleCall1() ' example call for using progress bar with a looping process  
    Dim pbar As Form_ProgressBar
    Dim i As Long Dim steps As Long 
    steps = 100000    
    ' create new instance of Progress Bar  
    Set pbar = New Form_ProgressBar  
    With pbar  ' #of steps, Mode, Caption  
        .init steps, PBarMode_Percent, "Hey, I'm working here!" 
        For i = 1 To steps  
            ' do something in a loop  
            ' update progress  
            .CurrentProgress = i  
        Next i 
    End With 
    Set pbar = Nothing
End Sub
```

Below is the method calling progress bar method

```
Public Sub ImportExcelfile(tblname As String, drpdwn As String)

Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelBook As New Excel.Workbook
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim rngDefine As Excel.Range

Dim objDialog As Object
Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
Dim strXls As String
On Error Resume Next

'Dialog box to select the excel file
     With objDialog
     .Title = "Select the Excel file to import"
     .AllowMultiSelect = False
     .Filters.Clear
     .Filters.Add "Excel Files macros enabled", "*.xlsm", 1
     .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2
     .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx", 3

If .Show = -1 Then
StrFileName = .SelectedItems(1)

     ExcelApp.Visible = False

     Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(StrFileName, False, True)

     Set rngDefine = ExcelBook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:AJ1")

     If IsError(ExcelApp.Match("text1", rngDefine, 0)) Then

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
        tablename:=drpdwn, _
        FileName:=StrFileName, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1!I:J", SpreadsheetType:=5


        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
        tablename:=tblname, _
        FileName:=StrFileName, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1!A:FK", SpreadsheetType:=5

     Else

MsgBox "File you trying to import contains one heading 'text1' in the first 
row.Please Delete it before importing"

End If

End With
  ExcelBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 Set ExcelBook = Nothing
ExcelApp.Quit
Set ExcelApp = Nothing

End sub
```

Code from where it is taking time to process is when opening the workbook and setting the range and checking for the perticular text1 in the excel sheet. In that i want to display progess bar

```
    Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(StrFileName, False, True)

    Set rngDefine = ExcelBook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:AJ1")

    If IsError(ExcelApp.Match("text1", rngDefine, 0)) Then
```

Comment: Hi @vuyy1182. I wrote that code. I'd be glad to help. What line of code does it highlight? Did you name your progress bar form exactly "ProgressBar"?

Comment: @ckuhn203, good coincidence. {Dim pbar As Form_ProgressBar} and { Set pbar = New orm_ProgressBar} causing error. I renamed it. And i have a doubt, can i call progress bar method in any of the situation like, when trying to import contents from excel to access, that time period i need to call the method.

Comment: Ok. If you renamed it, you'll need to change the object type. {Dim pbar as Form_"whateveryounamedit"} and {Set pbar = New Form_"whateveryounamedit"}. What you're actually doing is creating a new instance of that particular form object.

Comment: And yes, you should be able to call a new instance of the pbar form whenever. That actually sounds like an almost exact duplicate of the reason I designed it.

Comment: But in my situation i don't loop when transfering the contents to access, but in above method it has for loop to do steps and update the progress. How do i call the method in my situation. I'll post my code from where i'm calling progressbar method.

Comment: Yes. Please post your code. You may have to use "execute" mode.

Comment: I've edited my question and posted my code please have look

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50905/discussion-between-ckuhn203-and-vuyy1182)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've renamed the Progress Bar form, you'll need to change the object type.

```
Dim pbar as Form_YourNameHere
Set pbar = Neew Form_YourNameHere
```

Since there is no loop in your code, you will need to manually do some math and increment the CurrentProgress property of the pbar yourself. I've modified your code to do this. There aren't many steps, so the progress will "jump" a little bit.

```
Public Sub ImportExcelfile(tblname As String, drpdwn As String)

Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelBook As New Excel.Workbook
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim rngDefine As Excel.Range

Dim objDialog As Object
Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
Dim strXls As String

Dim pbar As Form_ProgressBar 'or whatever you named it

On Error Resume Next

'Dialog box to select the excel file
With objDialog
    .Title = "Select the Excel file to import"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files macros enabled", "*.xlsm", 1
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx", 3

If .Show = -1 Then
    StrFileName = .SelectedItems(1)

    ExcelApp.Visible = False

    Set pbar = New Form_ProgressBar 'again, whatever you named the form
    'There are 5 distinct steps to this code.
    pbar.init 5, PBarMode_Percent

    Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(StrFileName, False, True)

   'increment pbar
    pbar.CurrentProgress = 1 '20%

    Set rngDefine = ExcelBook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:AJ1")

    pbar.CurrentProgress = 2 '40%
    If IsError(ExcelApp.Match("text1", rngDefine, 0)) Then

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
        tablename:=drpdwn, _
        fileName:=StrFileName, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1!I:J", SpreadsheetType:=5

        'increment pbar
        pbar.CurrentProgress = 3 '60%

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
        tablename:=tblname, _
        fileName:=StrFileName, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1!A:FK", SpreadsheetType:=5

        'increment pbar
        pbar.CurrentProgress = 4 '80%
    Else
        ' remove progress bar on "error"
        Set pbar = Nothing

        MsgBox "File you trying to import contains one heading 'text1' in the first row.Please Delete it before importing"

    End If

End With
ExcelBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set ExcelBook = Nothing
xcelApp.Quit
Set ExcelApp = Nothing

'all done
pbar.CurrentProgress = 5 '100%
Set pbar = Nothing
End Sub
```

For anyone stumbling across this. OP is implementing the MS Access ProgressBar form I originally posted here. http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/progress-bar-for-ms-access/

Comment: One more thing, when it is loading text around the message is showing as black. how do i delete that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to set the "back style" property of the text box to "transparent" in form design mode.

Comment: I set it to tranperant. **Public Sub init() Method , Me.Text0 = "Ready"**.. only around the text **Ready** black color is appearing.